# Ограниченное кол-во символов в блоке WP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, текст

Сайт на WP, тема restaurant & cafe
Такая проблема: при выводе блока "избранное" с записью на главную страницу, выводится не весь желаемый текст записи (т.е. текст записи в блоке на главной обрезается до опр. значения, скрин прилагаю)
Отсюда вопрос: как можно отключить ограничение на длину текста? Ибо вывести надо чуть больше.
[[image: собственно, блок обрезает текст1]